# How to close Stripe PaymentSheet programatically from code in Android

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I have implemented Stripe PaymentIntent using JAVA code described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android).

I have opened this PaymentSheet in a separate Activity to display the timer above this sheet because we are not able to add any view in the PaymentSheet. I have achieved this by adding a timer view in the activity layout which is opening this PaymentSheet.

Now, I want to close the PaymentSheet programmatically when my timer gets off. I have tried to finish the activity when timer gets off but PaymentSheet keeps open and only the Activity gets finished. There is no method to close PaymentSheet from Stipe SDK. Stripe react-native SDK is having timeout parameter to close the PaymentSheet but similar thing is not available in the native Android SDK. [Reference for react-native](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/pull/1287)

Any idea/suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any direct support for this in the native SDKs, but you can inspect the [implementation details](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/pull/1287/files) of the `stripe-reactive-native` PR you references. Seeing how this was implemented for Android within React Native should allow you to follow a similar pattern with your own native app.